# How to get rid of YouTube notification number

Tags: youtube, notifications

I am a person who is *notiphobic* and I am trying for several days to get rid of YouTube's notification about someone's comment on my comment.
Its driving me nuts and I didn't find a resolution online.
[image]

Where do I go? I don't see this anywhere but that (1) is just not going away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on the menu (the 3 horizontal lines on the top left corner), then Settings -> Notifications.
2. Disable "Activity on my comments", "Replies to my comments". Also disable "Get Notifications on this browser" if you want to avoid to receive notifications when you are not using Youtube.

[image]